# "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, json, post, syntax-error

I receive this message when I make a post request.  I'm posting data from json list and posting it into a new list.  The initial post works, the 2nd time I click on the data I receive this error:

"POST http://localhost:3000/wishlist 500 (Internal Server Error)"
"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0"
"Error: Insert failed, duplicate id"

I believe it has to do with making a 2nd post request on the same ID, but I don't know how to fix it.

Below is the code:

```js
const postStadiumToWishList = (stadium) => {
    fetch(baseUrl + '/wishlist' , {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(stadium)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        stadiums.push(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: a) fix the error in the server code that causes it to crash the server with a HTTP 500 status b) fix the client code by not using `resp.json()` (that attempts to parse JSON) when receiving a text error

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I don't know how to do what you're suggesting

Comment: The first we can't help with, since you haven't shared the serverside code, for the second see http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html

Comment: server side code: I'm connecting to a db.json.  Is that what you're referring to with server side code?

Comment: don't blindly `resp => resp.json()` - check if `resp.ok` and handle the response as appropriate - *(hint: `resp.headers.get('content-type')` can help you determine which `resp.xxx()` to return, e.g. .json, .text, etc)* since when there is an error, the response is a string that isn't JSON - that'll fix the client code - as for the error from the server code - can't help, you don't show it

Comment: `server side code:` is the code that runs on the server, responding to your request on `/wishlist` with whatever it needs to

Comment: *I don't know how to fix it.* simple, don't make a 2nd post request on the same ID